# Grails Prevent HTML modifications

Tags: grails

I'm looking for a way to prevent HTML form user modifications, based on this example:

"User" entity has an enum Role (User, Administrator etc.) and there's a UserController that displays a g:form for first, last and email. Controller's action does user.properties = params.

How, a user can modify the HTML form with Firebug or Chrome Webdeveloper and rename textfield firstname to role and enter "Administrator" and will be granted Administrator rights.

There's useToken="true" and the withForm-closure, but this just seems to prevent the user to double-submit the same form. Beside this works with sessions and it's therefore not really scalable over multiple servers.

I'm using Grails 2.3.6. Is there a way to prevent such things except not using xxx.properties = params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a list of allowed properties. For your example:

```
user.properties['first', 'last', 'email'] = params
```

You should always give the list for security. Search in the grails documentation for 'Data Binding and Security Concerns'.

Comment: Thanks for the good input. But isn't there a way to ensure that form hasn't been modified, eg. hash all field names? I suppose this wasn't the purpose of useToken, right?

Comment: Yes you are right. useToken will prevent double-form-submit and Cross-site request forgery.